# Expression `in` when empty list (spring data jpa specification)

Tags: jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have this mission repository:

```
@Repository
interface MissionRepository: CrudRepository<MissionEntity, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<MissionEntity>
```

In my mission service class, I would like to fetch all missions that have their `countryId` parts of the given argument `Set`:

```
fun findAllByCountryIdIn(countryIds: Set<String>): List<MissionEntity> =
        missionRepository.findAll(where(countryIdIn(countryIds)))
}
```

Where `countryIdIn` (using `in` predicate) comes from:

```
class MissionSpecifications {
    companion object {
        fun countryIdIn(countryIds: Set<String>): Specification<MissionEntity> =
            Specification { root, _, _ -> root.get<String>("countryId").`in`(countryIds) }
    }
}
```

But when the `Set` is empty I got a predictable sql error. Is there a way to activate the where clause only when the given set is not empty? Without a if/else check? Maybe my specification syntax could be improve to avoid this sql error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather return earlier instead. So just don't add a where if you do not require it in the first place. You can do that in several ways, e.g. using [`takeIf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-if.html), a simple `if`, a `when`, etc.

Just listing some samples:

- [`takeIf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-if.html)

  ```
  fun findAllByCountryIdIn(countryIds: Set<String>) = countryIds.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }
               ?.let { missionRepository.findAll(where(countryIdIn(it))) } 
               ?: // what should be returned otherwise? emptyList? all? exception?
  ```
- [`ifEmpty` (Kotlin >=1.3)](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/08/kotlin-1-3-m2/)

  ```
  fun findAllByCountryIdIn(countryIds: Set<String>) = countryIds.ifEmpty {
    // what should be returned? emptyList? all entries?
  }.let {
    missionRepository.findAll(where(countryIdIn(it))) }
  }
  ```
- `if`

  ```
  fun findAllByCountryIdIn(countryIds: Set<String>) = if (countryIds.isEmpty()) /* what should be returned? */ 
                                                      else missionRepository.findAll(where(countryIdIn(countryIds))) }
  ```

If you just solve the `countryIdIn` instead, e.g. by passing an empty element, you give away the control of the query itself to the helper method. If you really want that, fine... but otherwise I wouldn't do that.

Why I wouldn't do that? If I return later to that specific code and read `findAll(where(countryIdIn(countryIds)))`. How long does it take me to understand for sure that I return all entries if the set is empty? Fact is: I can't without looking at `countryIdIn` itself. But that is my opinion.

Comment: Ok I thought spring data specification had a way to handle that.. I chose the `when` solution as I am not using Kotlin >= 1.3. Thnx

Comment: oh... I didn't want to say that spring data has no way to handle that... If you still want to handle it, you may just want to pass/return an empty specification as Jens Schauder wrote. Still... I think it will probably be better to be clear earlier in your method chain than later ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just put a test in the function creating the `Specification` if the set is empty and if it is, just return an empty `Specification`.

Answer (score 0):

An other solution would be:

```
@Repository
interface MissionRepository: JpaRepository<MissionEntity, String> {
    fun findByCountryIdIn(countryIds: Set<String>, pageable: Pageable): Page<MissionEntity>
}
```

where you can add pagination.